# What is the best option when integrating text files into sql in JBoss Fuse?

Tags: sql, jboss, integration, jbossfuse

I have to integrate text files into a Database using Jboss Fuse; do I have to use JDBC, which is the best approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Camel offers some easy ways to process a text file into a database.  (JDBC, SQL, Hibernate, JPA etc.)

For a small job, I'd be tempted to just use the SQL component-- it's pretty basic.

Github has some great examples provided by some very good books about Camel.  These are often cut-n-paste ready.

Good luck, there are good tools available.

Comment: Hello, Rick, thanks for your comments about Camel solutions for processing text files; I'll search GitHub examples about this. If you know another place with examples about this, please let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: You can find some database examples from Apache Camel here: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples#examples

Comment: And there is some JBoss Fuse examples here (for various versions so take note) - https://github.com/FuseByExample